# Can we use $|A|=|B|$ to prove $|A| \le|B|$ and $|B| \le|A|$ directly in the set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Recently, when I self-learned Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th by Kenneth Rosen, I did only the even-numbered exercises which the author offers the detailed description than the odd ones because the odd ones and the corresponding even ones are very similar. I was stuck at exercise 2.5-14.

The problem is

> Show that if A and B are sets with the same cardinality,
> then $|A| \le|B|$ and $|B| \le|A|$

The book solution uses "one-to-one" and "onto" of $A\to B$ definition to prove $|A| \le|B|$ and $|B| \le|A|$ respectively.

Q:

Maybe the solution by the book takes the uncountably infinite set in account and since *comparing $\infty$* is nonsense, so it use the basic definition to prove the inequalities, is it that case? If not, can we use the *arithmetic* property to prove $\le$ directly from $=$ which applied here will give the *converse* statement of the SCHRODER-BERNSTEIN THEOREM?

Comment: Please combine your questions into one

Comment: Thanks for the comment, modified already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how cardinality is defined for infinite sets. If $A$ and $B$ or finite, this is trivial.

When working with infinite sets there is very little reason to think that any coherent notion of "size" exists in the first place.

*If* you fix a particular notion of cardinality, so that each set has a cardinality and the set of cardinals less than the cardinality of a given set is ordered, then you *can* use the arithmetic definition $a=b\iff(a\le b\land b\le a)$. Typically this is done by defining $\lvert X\rvert$ to be the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that there exists a bijection $f:\alpha\to X$, and each such ordinal is regarded as a cardinal.

However, in the general setting, we may or may not have ordinals, or any way of assigning sets specific cardinalities. What we *do* have is a notion of "equipotence." Two sets $A$ and $B$ are said to be equipotent if and only if there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$. Thus, regardless of what "$\lvert A\rvert$" and "$\lvert B\rvert$" "actually" mean (if they mean anything at all), we can *always* take $\lvert A\rvert=\lvert B\rvert$ to mean "there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$". Similarly, we can interpret $\lvert A\rvert\le\lvert B\rvert$ as "there exists an injection from $A$ to $B$." This makes sense: obviously $\lvert A\rvert=\lvert f(A)\rvert$, and $f(A)\subseteq B$, so there should be *at most* $B$-many elements in $A$.

What this all leads to is the Schröder–Bernstein theorem. What the theorem actually states is that for any pair of sets $A$ and $B$, if there exist injections $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$, then there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$. In other words: $(\lvert A\rvert\le\lvert B\rvert\land\lvert B\rvert\le\lvert A\rvert)\implies\lvert A\rvert=\lvert B\rvert$.

What you are trying to prove *is* the converse of the Schröder–Bernstein theorem:

Suppose there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$. Prove that there exist injections from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$.

---

For a quick 'n' dirty introduction to ordinals and cardinals, I would recommend Vsauce's *[How to count past infinity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrU9YDoXE88)*

Comment: Thanks. I have understood what you said. With your answer "there is very little reason to think that any coherent notion of "size" exists in the first place.", "equipotence" is necessary for comparing two uncountably infinite sets.

Answer (score 2):

Proof. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are sets with the same cardinality. I.e., $\vert A \vert = \vert B \vert$. By definition, there is a bijective mapping $f$ from $A$ to $B$. Since $f : A \to B$ is bijective, $f^{-1} : B \to A$ is also bijective. Since $f$ is bijective, it is also injective. Hence, $\vert A \vert \le \vert B \vert$. Furthermore, since $f^{-1}$ is bijective it is also injective. Therefore, $\vert B \vert \le \vert A \vert$. Our conclusion has been reached. $\blacksquare$

As for your question, I believe that your text uses the definition of cardinality to make the comparison $\vert A \vert \le \vert B \vert$. If you wish to use the arithmetic property $a = b \Leftrightarrow a \le b \text{ and } b \le a$, your conclusion would be restricted to natural numbers. In this context, you would be limited to finite sets. But, the given statement is actually stronger. It allows you to say something about the ordering of sets of arbitrary size. That, if you can construct a bijection from $A$ to $B$ and $\vert A \vert = \aleph_{100}$, then you automatically know that $\vert B \vert = \aleph_{100}$ and $\aleph_{100} \le \aleph_{100}$.

Comment: 1. Your answer is also very helpful and similar to the accepted one, but only one answer can be chosen as accepted. 2. To answer "I believe that your text uses the definition of cardinality to make the comparison $|A|\le|B|$", the textbook states "If there is a one-to-one function from A to B, the cardinality of A is less than or the same as the cardinality of B and we write $|A|\le|B|$" as you said.